# Extract the row of specific values with certain frequency

Tags: python

Say we have the list of `df.Food.value.counts()[:4]`

```
 apple   50 
 sausage 20
 banana  20
 cheese  10
```

How to extract the rows of df where the value of Food is on the list above?

Comment: What is  the type of `df.Food`

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai the dtype is objects

Comment: looks like you are using pandas, can you provide the dataset you are working and what will be desired output.

Comment: Actually I am working on MoMA dataset https://github.com/MuseumofModernArt/collection, would like to extract the rows of Top 20 Credit who donated/sold the biggest no. of work to the museum. I just got the list of Credit by `artworks.Credit.value_counts()[:20]` @pygo